# Need help isolating specific parts of a csv into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to open a specific part of a csv file into a pandas dataframe. Here is what the start of the csv file looks like:

```
AMZN,"[{'cik': '0001018724', 'file': '\n<TYPE>10-K\n<SEQUENCE>1\n<FILENAME>amzn-20161231x10k.htm\n<DESCRIPTION>FORM 10-K\n<TEXT>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"">\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<!-- Document created using Wdesk 1 -->\n\t\t<!-- Copyright 2017 Workiva -->\n\t\t<title>Document</title>\n\t</head>\n\t<body style=""font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;"">\n<div><a name=""s00CB6310C0A752A3B7DA1FF03AF57C4C""></a></div><div style=""line-height:120%;text-align:center;font-size:10pt;""><div style=""padding-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:normal;padding-top:10px;""><table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" style=""font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;""><tr><td colspan=""1""></td></tr><tr><td style=""width:100%;""></td></tr><tr><td style=""vertical-align:bottom;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;border-top:1px solid #000000;""><div style=""overflow:hidden;height:5px;font-size:10pt;""><font style=""font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;"">&#160;</font></div></td></tr></table></div></div><div style=""line-height:120%;text-align:center;font-size:16pt;""><font style=""font-family:inherit;font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;"">UNITED STATES</font></div><div style=""line-height:120%;text-align:center;font-size:16pt;""><font style=""font-family:inherit;font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;"">SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION
```

As you can notice, it starts with a company ticker, followed by a list of dictionaries in quotation marks. Each dictionary has 4 keys (you can see 2 in the snippet above, 'cik' and 'file') and there's about 100 dictionaries in the list for each ticker (each dictionary containing the same keys but with data from different time periods) and 17 tickers overall. So to summarise, it is like this:
ticker, "[{},{},{}...]" 
followed by the next ticker

What I would like to do is to open this csv into a pandas df with 2 columns, the first having the tickers and the second containing the information contained in a specific key in the list of dictionaries. This key is called 'file', you can see it in the csv snippet above. For each ticker it will appear about 100 times as there are about 100 dictionaries per ticker and each dictionary has the 'file' key followed by a long string of html text.

I have tried to open it with the usual read_csv as such

```
ten_k_data_csv = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='output_final_cleaned_for_manipulation.csv', header=None)
```

But it just opens into a 17x2 df, with 1 row for each ticker and the first column containing the ticker symbol and the second column containing the entire list of dictionaries as a string. I cannot utilise any of the df manipulations that I have learnt to isolate the information I want as the 'file' key appears many times per row. The dataframe I want should instead be about 1700 rows, as I want each individual dictionary to be its own row.

Alternatively, if there are ways to manipulate the csv file directly through code to get it to isolate the 'file' keys and tickers and delete everything else, I don't actually need to load it into a pandas dataframe. I just usually load data in pandas dataframes as it, most of the time, makes the data easier to manipulate. But in this case, I have no idea where to start. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: I tried opening it as I would normally read a csv into a df, but from there nothing else seems to work. I tried a for loop with iterrows() but because the column with the data I want read in as one GIANT string, I cannot use the usual .loc and .iloc stuff I know of to isolate what I want.  I thought maybe pandas would read in the file and separate the dictionaries for me, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I thought about maybe specifying a delimiter but it wouldn't really solve what I want either.

Comment: Just a guess but what you have is a html file, try read html?

Comment: It isn't exactly an html file. One of the keys contains the unedited html data scraped from the website. But the other 2 keys contain cleaned (remove html tags, lowercased, etc) and lemmatised versions of the data. And the first key contains the CIK number of each company. I might need to isolate the other versions later, so I wanted to figure out how to do it. Thus, I don't think read html would help here